# Django queries related objects

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Então com dois modelos criados :

```py
class Questao(models.Model):
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str(self):
        return str(self.text)

    def get_answers(self):
        return self.resposta_set.all()

    class Meta :
        verbose_name = "Questão"
        verbose_name_plural = "Questões"


class Resposta(models.Model):
    texto = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    correto = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    questao = models.ForeignKey(Questao, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="respostas")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

a função que criei para relacionar ambos os objetos "get_answers" esta com um erro visível

````
in get_answers
    return self.resposta_set.all()
AttributeError: 'Questao' object has no attribute 'resposta_set'
```
Podem me explicar como funciona o **_set** no django, e por que essa função não retorna nenhum atributo por favor ?
````

Answer (score 0):

Pela sua pergunta pressuponho que você gostaria de listar as respostas de uma questão no método get_answers, logo entendo que ele deveria ser algo parecido com isso:

```
def get_answers(self):
    return Resposta.objects.filter(questao=self)
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma outra solução seria essa:

```
def get_answers(self):
    return self.respostas.all()
```

Usa o related_name definido.